# Foundation 3.0.5 installing issue with rails 3.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile, zurb-foundation, bundle-install

I just started a new project and added zurb-foundation to the Gemfile.
Bundle install show a sass compatibility problem so i run bundle update and bundle install and everything seems ok.

But when I do rails g foundation:install as said in the documentation (https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails) it's telling me : Could not find generator foundation:install.
Yet I did bundle install so I don't understand.

Thanks for any help !
Here is my Gemfile :

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 3.0.5'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

And the result of bundle install :

```
Using rake (0.9.2.2)   
Using i18n (0.6.0)   
Using multi_json (1.3.6)   
Using activesupport (3.2.6)   
Using builder (3.0.0)   
Using activemodel (3.2.6)   
Using erubis (2.7.0)   
Using journey (1.0.4)   
Using rack (1.4.1)   
Using rack-cache (1.2)   
Using rack-test (0.6.1)   
Using hike (1.2.1)   
Using tilt (1.3.3)   
Using sprockets (2.1.3)   
Using actionpack (3.2.6)   
Using mime-types (1.19)   
Using polyglot (0.3.3)   
Using treetop (1.4.10)   
Using mail (2.4.4)   
Using actionmailer (3.2.6)   
Using arel (3.0.2)   
Using tzinfo (0.3.33)   
Using activerecord (3.2.6)   
Using activeresource (3.2.6)   
Using bundler (1.1.3)   
Using chunky_png (1.2.5)   
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3)   
Using execjs (1.4.0)   
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)   
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)   
Using json (1.7.3)   
Using rdoc (3.12)   
Using thor (0.15.4)   
Using railties (3.2.6)   
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)   
Using fssm (0.2.9)   
Using sass (3.2.0.alpha.261)   
Using compass (0.12.2)   
Using jquery-rails (2.0.2)   
Using rails (3.2.6)   
Using sass-rails (3.2.5)   
Using sqlite3 (1.3.6)   
Using uglifier (1.2.6)   
Using zurb-foundation (3.0.5)
```

Comment: Managed to it with http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/gem-install.php#simple2.
Github documentation is not up to date.
The navigation bar is showing but the dropdown list is not working (taking from the example) So much troubles for an easy task ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to do it with foundation.zurb.com/docs/gem-install.php#simple2.
Github documentation is not up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Since the links above are no longer correct, for Foundation 3.0, use

```
compass create <project-name> -r zurb-foundation --using foundation
```

(can be found on the [Foundation Documentation: Compass](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/compass.php) page)